# Pseudochange of Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis, pseudoinverse

I have a question regarding a change of basis and the pseudoinverse.

Let $\mathit{B}_{1}$ and $\mathit{B}_{2}$ be basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ with square $2 \times 2$ $\mathit{A}$ matrix describing $\mathit{B}_{2}$ in terms of $\mathit{B}_{1}$. Some transformation $\mathit{T}_{2}$ described in $\mathit{B}_{2}$ maps vector $\mathbf{x}_{2}$ described in $\mathit{B}_{2}$ to vector $\mathbf{y}_{2}$ described in $\mathit{B}_{2}$. If I wanted to apply transformation $\mathit{T}_{2}$ to a vector $\mathbf{x}_{1}$ described in $\mathit{B}_{1}$, I believe:

$$
\begin{equation}
\mathit{T}_{1} = \mathit{A}\mathit{T}_{2}\mathit{A}^{-1}
\end{equation}
\tag{1}
\label{eq1}
$$

$$
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{y}_{1} = \mathit{T}_{1} \mathbf{x}_{1}.
\end{equation}
\tag{2}
\label{eq2}
$$

Now let $\mathit{B}_{3}$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ with rectangular $2 \times 3$ matrix $\mathit{C}$ describing $\mathit{B}_{3}$ in terms of $\mathit{B}_{1}$. Some transformation $\mathit{M}_{3}$ described in $\mathit{B}_{3}$ maps vector $\mathbf{x}_{3}$ described in $\mathit{B}_{3}$ to vector $\mathbf{w}_{3}$ described in $\mathit{B}_{3}$. If I wanted to apply transformation $\mathit{M}_{3}$ to $\mathbf{x}_{1}$, could I use the right pseudoinverse to apply a "pseudo-change of basis" (I'm not sure what the correct term is here):

$$
\begin{equation}
\mathit{M}_{1} = \mathit{C}\mathit{M}_{3}\mathit{C}^{~+}
\end{equation}
\tag{3}
\label{eq3}
$$

$$
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{w}_{1} = \mathit{M}_{1} \mathbf{x}_{1}
\end{equation}
\tag{4}
\label{eq4}
$$

where

$$
\begin{equation}
\mathit{C}^{~+} = \mathit{C}^{\mathsf{~T}} \left(\mathit{C}\mathit{C}^{\mathsf{~T}} \right)^{-1} ?
\end{equation}
\tag{5}
\label{eq}
$$

Further, if $\mathit{M}_{3}$ simply scaled the components of $\mathbf{x}_{3}$, such as $\mathit{M}_{3} = diag\{0.5 ~~ 1  ~~ 2 \}$, what would $\mathit{M}_{1}$ do to $\mathbf{x}_{1}$?

Sorry if the above math is confusing. I'm an engineering student trying my best. Thanks!